# R package source install, no compiler

Tags: r

I am trying to install some packages from source on a linux (RHEL) server.  But whenever the package requires some C++ compilation it fails.

For example, I try to install `Ckmeans.1d.dp` package.  If I call `R CMD INSTALL Ckmeans.1.dp_4.2.1.tar.gz` I get the following output (truncated) where you can see the compiler is omitted.

```
...* installing *source* package ‘Ckmeans.1d.dp’ ...
** libs
I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include       -c Ckmeans.1d.dp.cpp -o Ckmeans.1d.dp.o
make: I/usr/include/R: Command not found
...
-shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o Ckmeans.1d.dp.so Ckmeans.1d.dp.o Ckmeans.1d.dp_main.o dynamic_prog.o fill_SMAWK.o fill_log_linear.o fill_quadratic.o select_levels.o weighted_select_levels.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/bin/sh: line 2: -shared: command not found
make: *** [Ckmeans.1d.dp.so] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Ckmeans.1d.dp’
```

I am currently stuck with a server that only has R 3.1.1 and I do not have admin privileges.  The `$Rhome/etc/Makeconf` has `CXX` and `CC` defined.  I have also verified `g++` and `gcc` are installed.

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Invariably an environment variable with an 'empty' value gets expanded.  Maybe (just guessing here) the package would use C++11, so `$(CXX11} -shared` gets expanded and ... becomes `-shared` and an error is triggered.

Look at the R settings, eg via `less $(R HOME)/etc/Makevars` and see what it expects.

I think you can get by, if you must, installing `gcc` et al below, say, `~/bin`.  Some packages will require a compiler...

Comment: That appears to be the problem Dirk. I extracted the tar file and commented out the c++11 requirement and the compiler is back (although crashes now).  Now I just need to deal with getting IT to update the compiler at the very least.  Thanks for the insight.